# Using API of Philips Hue Activate/Deactivate Scene created via Philips Hue App

Tags: android, scene, philips-hue

I tried many solutions but don't get the accurate solution.

Tried following API details

- http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/java-sdk-getting-started#usingScenes
- http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/scenes-api (Login Required)

I received list of scenes using the following API

http://localhost/api/newdeveloper/scenes  (Working well in emulator and device)

Now, I want to Activate or Deactivate particular scene from the list just like Philips Hue App does.

Let me know, if any more info is needed for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say activate the scene,  do you mean recall it?  If so this is done with the Groups API
http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/scenes-api#44_recall_scene (Login Required)
http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/groups-api#253_body_example (Login Required)

This is not to be confused with the 'active' boolean on the scenes. The active flag is used by the bridge to indicate when the scene can be used, and is read-only.